Get param from SSO on pre auth state
There is the following configuration:

ADFS and;
website like some.com  in trusted host browser configuration;
site have two "path" like 'path1' and 'path2';
path1 look to sso1 and path2 to sso2

It is possibly on first login from AD PC before auth detect path from SSO clains or some another params?
Tagret:
On first login redirect user to some.com/path1 or some.com/path2
Он this path start SSO auth with specific params.
